# Return value of key in nested dict when key not present in all nested dicts

Tags: python

Trying to get the values of a particular key from nested dictionaries, but the key is not always present. The key in question is 'action'. I tried several ways but can't get it right. I either get an error saying the key doesnt exist, or I get a partial return. My latest attempts are as follows.

```
def events_query():
    query_res = {
    'took': 52, 
    'timed_out': False, 
    '_shards': {
        'total': 3, 
        'successful': 3, 
        'skipped': 1, 
        'failed': 0
        }, 
    'hits': {
        'total': {'value': 10000, 'relation': 'gte'}, 
        'max_score': None, 
        'hits': [

            {
                '_index': 'winlogbeat-dc-2023.01.16-000195', 
                '_type': '_doc', 
                '_id': '_LrxCYYBiABa0UinUkYt', 
                '_score': None, 
                '_source': {
                    'agent': {'hostname': 'SRVDCMI'}, 
                    'event': {
                        'code': '7036', 
                        'provider': 'Service Control Manager', 
                        'created': '2023-01-31T22:27:34.585Z', 
                        'kind': 'event'
                        }
                    }, 
            'sort': [-9223372036854775808]
                }, 
            {
                '_index': 'winlogbeat-dc-2023.01.16-000195', 
                '_type': '_doc', 
                '_id': '_brxCYYBiABa0UinUkYt', 
                '_score': None, 
                '_source': {
                    'agent': {'hostname': 'SRVDCMI'}, 
                    'event': {
                        'code': '7036', 
                        'provider': 'Service Control Manager', 
                        'kind': 'event', 
                        'created': '2023-01-31T22:27:34.585Z'
                        }
                    }, 
                'sort': [-9223372036854775808]
                }, 
            {
                '_index': 'winlogbeat-dc-2023.01.16-000195', 
                '_type': '_doc', 
                '_id': '_rrxCYYBiABa0UinUkYt', 
                '_score': None, 
                '_source': {
                    'agent': {'hostname': 'SRVDCMI'}, 
                    'event': {
                        'code': '7036', 
                        'provider': 'Service Control Manager', 
                        'kind': 'event', 
                        'created': '2023-01-31T22:27:34.585Z'
                        }
                    }, 
                'sort': [-9223372036854775808]
                }, 
            {
                '_index': 'winlogbeat-dc-2023.01.16-000195', 
                '_type': '_doc', 
                '_id': '_7rxCYYBiABa0UinUkZI', 
                '_score': None, 
                '_source': {
                    'agent': {'hostname': 'SRVDC01'}, 
                    'event': {
                        'code': '4624', 
                        'provider': 'Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing', 
                        'created': '2023-01-31T22:27:34.622Z', 
                        'kind': 'event', 
                        'module': 'security', 
                        'action': 'logged-in', 
                        'category': ['authentication'], 
                        'type': ['start'], 
                        'outcome': 'success'
                        }
                    }, 
                'sort': [-9223372036854775808]
                }, 
            {
                '_index': 'winlogbeat-dc-2023.01.16-000195', 
                '_type': '_doc', 
                '_id': 'ALrxCYYBiABa0UinUkdI', 
                '_score': None, 
                '_source': {
                    'agent': {'hostname': 'SRVDC01'}, 
                    'event': {
                        'code': '4776', 
                        'provider': 'Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing', 
                        'created': '2023-01-31T22:27:34.622Z', 
                        'kind': 'event', 
                        'module': 'security', 
                        'action': 'credential-validated', 
                        'category': ['authentication'], 
                        'type': ['start'], 
                        'outcome': 'success'
                        }
                    }, 
                'sort': [-9223372036854775808]
          
                }]}}

    for q in query_res:
        if 'action' in query_res['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['event']:
            print(query_res['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['event']['action'])
        else:
            print('not found')

   #or

   action = query_res['hits']['hits']
   action_list = [a['_source']['event']['action'] for a in action]
   print(action_list)

events_query()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to look for the key in a specific part of the dictionary? Can it be in more than one place? For the specific input that you show, exactly what should the result be, and why? Can you demonstrate the problem with simpler input data? Please read [mre]. "Any help is appreciated." - that [is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236), and cannot be answered as such. Please try to be specific and explicit about what you want us to tell you.

Comment: what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Just fyi the loop `for q in query_res` loops through it's keys. You're not even using `q` in that loop therefore no need to even loop.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel This is a simple data, Karl. This is part of a much larger script. The output is basically a Pandas dataframe showing the 'code' key and the 'action' key in a table. The problem is that I'm getting an error when the data doesnt have all the keys (in this case 'action'). That is a mystery to me, but that is a Elasticsearch issue. 
So what I'm trying to do is to bbypass the indices that dont have this 'action' key as a temporary solution.

Comment: @Jab Please see my response to Karl

Comment: @RobinSage, do you want to filter out `None` actions (if not found) from `action_list`?

Comment: "a simple data" should not take several dozen lines. We have very particular standards for questions here. Again, please read [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `query_res` dictionary has a nested dictionary with the key `hits` which has a list with the key `hits`. That's the list you want to loop over. The dictionaries in that list contain `_source` keys that point to dictionaries with the `event` key. That's where you need to look for `action`s.

```
for hh in query_res['hits']['hits']:
    if 'action' in hh['_source']['event']:
        print(hh['_source']['event']['action'])
    else:
        print('not found')
```

Output:

```
not found
not found
not found
logged-in
credential-validated
```

Right now `action` is the only key that's being tested before it's being accessed. If any of the other keys are optional, you might want to test for those as well, or use Python's `dict.get` method to provide a default.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a little helper function that will recursively go through the hierarchy, validating the presence of keys as it drills down:

```
def findKey(D,key,*more,default=None):
    try:    
        return findKey(D[key],*more,default=default) if more else D[key]
    except: 
        return default

V = findKey(query_res,"hits","hits",0,"_source","event","action",default="Not Found")
print(V) 
# Not Found

V = findKey(query_res,"hits","hits",0,"_source","event",default="Not Found")
print(V) 
# {'code': '7036', 'provider': 'Service Control Manager', 
   'created': '2023-01-31T22:27:34.585Z', 'kind': 'event'}
```